# recursive mergesort function analysis

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode

need some help with question from Data Structure course:
I was given this recursive function of mergesort (pseudo code):

```
Mergesort_1/3(A, p, r)
if p < r 
    then q = (p+(r-p)/3) // round the result down
        Mergesort_1/3 (A,p,q)            
                Mergesort_1/3 (A,q+1,r)
                Merge(A,p,q,r)
```

and these are the questions:

1. Let T(n) be the worst case running time of Mergesort _1/3. Write the recursive function for T(n). Give a short explanation.
2. Prove that T(n)=Ω(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

The gist of classic mergesort is the following recursion:

- Split an unordered list in half.
  It suffices to compute the limit offsets of the partial lists.
- Apply the mergesort to each of the partial lists.
  After this step, the partial lists will be sorted.
- Merge the sorted partial lists by inspecting the elements of both lists in their respective order, coyping from and progressing in the list with the smaller element.

Let `TC(n)` be the time complexity of classic mergesort. The aforementioned steps take `O(1)` (*), `2*O(TC(ceil(n/2)))`, and `O(n)`, respectively. This lends to the recursion `TC(n) = cc_0 + cc_1 * n + 2 * TC(ceil(n/2))`.

Consider the generalized mergesort where lists are split unevenly, though always with the same ratio. The complexity of splitting and merging remains the same, lending to the recursion `TG(n) = ca_0 + ca_1 * n + TG(1/a * n + 1) + TG((a-1)/a * n + 1))` for the generalized mergesort (using `TG(x+1)` instead of `TG(ceil(x))`; `ca_0`, `ca_1` being the constants hidden in the `O(_)` notation; `a=3` for `mergesort_1/3`).

This recurrence can be solved using the [Akra-Bazzi-Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).
To this end, the recurrence needs to be written as

```
TG(x) = g(x) + \sum_i=1..k ( a_i * TG(b_i * x + h_i(x) ) ; x >= x_0.
```

with

```
a_i, b_i const.
a_i > 0
0 < b_i < 1
|g(x)| = O(x^c); c const.
|h(x)| = O(x / (log(x))^2)
```

which can be done by setting ...

```
k      = 2 
a_1    = 1
a_2    = 1
b_1    = 1/a
b_2    = (a-1)/a
g(x)   = ca_0 + ca_1 * x 
h_1(x) = 1
h_2(x) = 1
x_0    = 2

-> TG(x) = ca_0 + ca_1 * n + 1 * TG(1/a * x + 1 ) + 1 * TG((a-1)/a * x + 1 ) ; x >= x_0.
```

The Akra-Bazzi theorem requires the exponent `p` be found in `\sum_i=1..k ( a_i * (b_i)^p ) = 1`. Then the following holds:

```
TG(x) = Θ ( x^p \integral_(1, x) ( g(u) / (u^(p+1)) du ) )
```

Specifically,

```
    a_1 * b_1^p + a_2 * b_2^p = 1
 => (1/a)^p + ((a-1)/a)^p     = 1
<=> p = 1
```

... and thus ...

```
TG(x) = Θ ( x \integral_(1, x) ( (ca_0 + ca_1 * u) / u^2 du ) )
      = Θ ( x [ - ca_0/u + ca_1 * log(u) ]_(1,x) )
      = Θ ( - ca_0 + ca_1 * x * log(x) + ca_0 * x - ca_1 * x * log(1) )
      = Θ (x * log(x))
```

(*) Strictly speaking this is incorrect since basic arithmetics on binary representations and memory access is `O(log n)`. However, this makes no difference asymptotically for `Θ(n log n)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two, this mergesort makes partitions the data in three equal size chunks. So you are reducing a problem of size n to three problems of size n/3. Further, when merging, you will have to go through all the three n/3 sized sorted chunks which will result in going through total n elements. Hence, the recurrence can be written as:

- T(n) = 3 T(n / 3) + O(n)

[Using Master Theorem](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf): Here a = 3, b = 3 and c = 1. Log<sub>b</sub>a = Log<sub>3</sub>3 = 1 = c.

So the recurrence will fall in the second case and T(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup> * Log(n)) =  Θ(n * Log(n)).